# Set timeout for query operation using CloudTable Object

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-storage

I am querying a table storage using a Cloud Table object as follows:

```
   private CloudTable _table

   _table.ExecuteQuery(query);
```

It takes too much time before it throws an exception. How can i change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're two timeouts to consider - **server timeout** and the **client timeout**. Server timeout is the time span after which Table Service will timeout the request. You can set that through [ServerTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablerequestoptions.servertimeout.aspx) property of [TableRequestOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj733154.aspx) class.

So your code would look something like:

```
var tableRequestOptions = new TableRequestOptions()
{
    ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),//Will timeout request on the server after 30 seconds
};
CloudTable _table;
_table.ExecuteQuery(query, tableRequestOptions);
```

Comment: What about the client timeout?

Comment: There is one more timeout to consider which is MaximumExecutionTime which "Gets or sets the maximum execution time for all potential retries for the request"

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tablerequestoptions.maximumexecutiontime.aspx

Answer (score -4):

Add this in to **Web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
             <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```